# Pickadate is not understanding my existing date

Tags: jquery, pickadate

I'm using [pickadate](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/):

I have a picker that have his initial value to: 2016-04-14 (yyyy-mm-dd), but when I open the picker, this date is not selected.

When I select a new date, format change in input, to 14 April 2016, I don't want this behaviour....

Here is my jquery:

```
var fecha = $('.fecha[data-id=' + count + ']');
console.log(fecha.val()); // gives 2016-04-01
fecha.pickadate({

    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    today: 'hoy',
    formatSubmit: 'yyyy-mm-dd'

});

var picker = fecha.pickadate();

picker.on({
    start: function () {
        picker.set('select', fecha.val(), {format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'})
    }
});
```

I can't find a way with [apis](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/api/)

Any idea what's wrong??

Comment: It should do this by default. Can you make a codepen or something with this that reproduces your issue?

Comment: I tried, but I can't make the pen work :( my first pen.... http://codepen.io/xoco79/pen/JXLJwQ

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your earlier pen, I think your problem isn't actually code, but CSS. [Here's a pen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxqyQM) that has the CSS included, and seems to function as you are intending. The CSS was likely missing for the "highlighted" date.

```
.picker__day--highlighted
```

should be the relevant CSS class. I copied in the CSS from one of their example codepens.